# Should wood be treated or sealed before tiling?

Tags: tile

Building two service shelves next to a BBQ shack, that's exposed to Oregon weather. I intend to use HB over the wood. Should the wood be sealed first before using the HB, then apply the tile?

Comment: What is "***HB***"?

Comment: I think it stands for Hardie Board?

Answer (score 1):

The wood should be pressure-treated or naturally rot-resistant.

Sealing the surface may reduce warpage, but will have limited effect on long-term rot issues.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use a waterproof barrier between cementitious tile board and wood in wet applications. Tile grout and hardibacker and wonderboard and concrete and any other cement based material is porous and water will eventually penetrate. For your application a "cold applied" black waterproofer (in lieu of the normal hot-mop asphalt) could be used, you can get it at a tile supply store. Or at least put down some craft paper that is fastened above the shelf in back and overlaps the front edge to allow penetrating moisture to "weep" away off the front edge.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use pressure treated wood if it is under both HB and tile.  It won't see moisture and PT wood warps more as it looses moisture.  You could also Redgard your HB before tiling.

Also HB is not supposed to be used outside according to manufacturer.  Would I use it outside in your situation. Yes.  But just throwing that out there.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use hardibacker outside; I'd use a cementitious (durock etc.) instead. And then I'd use a waterproofer/isolation membrane like Ditra. This will not only waterproof things, it will also provide some isolation against movement and cracking.